# How do I achieve serialization with immutable types?

Tags: c#, serialization, immutability, .net-standard

I want to create a new type to represent a chat message. According to the [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) guidelines, I should avoid using structs unless it the size is under 16 bytes and logically represents a single value. It's not exactly a primitive type, so a struct would be out of the question.

For my type, it makes sense to implement value equality. This, in turn, means I need to override `GetHashCode`, which in turn means my type should be immutable. That's fine, being immutable makes sense.

However, my type needs to be serializable. How would I make it possible to deserialize my type while still leaving it immutable? Preferably in a way that isn't tied to a particular library or serializer; bonus points if it's compatible with .NET Standard.

Comment: It depends on specific serializer. Most of them are capable of calling private setters \ setting private fields, some do not (and some do not only in specific environments). Other serializers provide a way to customize serialization process (like `IXmlSerializable` or `ISerializable` interfaces).

Comment: But, if you need "one size fits all" - you can provide corresponding class for your immutable one, which will be mutable and will be used for deserialization. This class will have implicit conversion to and from immutable one. Like described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16076068/5311735